# create a table using google slides API

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I am trying to make a new slide that contains a table with some data in it using the Google Slides API.
I'm getting an invalid JSON payload error.

What i've tried to do is create a function that makes the new table request.

```
def make_table_obj(self, data):
    '''make a table object to be added to a slide'''
    keys = [key for key in data[0].keys()]
    return {
        "objectId": gen_id(),
        "pageType": "SLIDE",
        "pageElements": [
            {"elementGroup": {
                "table": {
                    "rows": len(data),
                    "columns": len(data[0].keys()),
                    "tableRows": [
                        [
                            {
                                "text": data[i][keys[k]],
                                "location": {"rowIndex": i, "columnIndex": k}
                            } for k in range(int(len(keys)))
                        ]
                        for i in range(int(len(data)))
                        ]}
        }}]
        }
```

Here's some sample data to help you help me

```
[{'_id': 'Customer Service',
  'metric1': 239.0,
  'metric2': 1875.0},
 {'_id': 'Order',
  'metric1': 2846.0,
  'metric2': 5171.0},
 {'_id': 'Checkout',
  'metric1': 1789.0,
  'metric2': 2446.0}]
```

The function produces the request that I want(I think), but I am getting this error.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/<presentationId>:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[1].create_shape.shape_type' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.slides.v1.Shape.Type), "Table"
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "rows" at 'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "columns" at 'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "tableRows" at 'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[1].create_shape.shape_type', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'requests[1].create_shape.shape_type\' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.slides.v1.Shape.Type), "Table"'}, {'field': 'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "rows" at \'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties\': Cannot find field.'}, {'field': 'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "columns" at \'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties\': Cannot find field.'}, {'field': 'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "tableRows" at \'requests[1].create_shape.element_properties\': Cannot find field.'}]}]">
```

Here's the full request that I am sending.

```
[
 {
  "objectId": "id-1617143529-776043",
  "pageType": "SLIDE",
  "pageElements": [
   {
    "elementGroup": {
     "table": {
      "rows": 23,
      "columns": 3,
      "tableRows": [
       [
        {
         "text": "Customer Service",
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 0
         }
        },
        {
         "text": 239.0,
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 1
         }
        },
        {
         "text": 1875.0,
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 2
         }
        }
       ],
       [
        {
         "text": "Order",
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 0
         }
        },
        {
         "text": 2846.0,
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 1
         }
        },
        {
         "text": 5171.0,
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 2
         }
        }
       ],
       [
        {
         "text": "Checkout",
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 0
         }
        },
        {
         "text": 1789.0,
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 1
         }
        },
        {
         "text": 2446.0,
         "location": {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 2
         }
        }
       ],
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Thanks in advance if you can help, I know this question is a bit long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Table Operations](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/tables) for creating and editing table data.

**Example Request Body:**

**Note:** *The request below will create a new slide with id `id-1617139878-856039` and insert a table with data in it.*

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createSlide": {
        "objectId": "id-1617139878-856039",
        "insertionIndex": 9,
        "slideLayoutReference": {
          "predefinedLayout": "TITLE"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "createTable": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "elementProperties": {
          "pageObjectId": "id-1617139878-856039"
        },
        "rows": 3,
        "columns": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 0
        },
        "text": "Customer Service"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 1
        },
        "text": "239.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 0,
          "columnIndex": 2
        },
        "text": "1875.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 0
        },
        "text": "Order"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 1
        },
        "text": "2846.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 1,
          "columnIndex": 2
        },
        "text": "2846.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 0
        },
        "text": "Checkout"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 1
        },
        "text": "1789.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "objectId": "123456",
        "cellLocation": {
          "rowIndex": 2,
          "columnIndex": 2
        },
        "text": "2446.0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I tested the request here: [Google Slide API batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)

Answer (score 0):

After spending many hours on this... I got it to work where I added the table by first creating the slides using the API. However, when I tried to run the same function (that worked) from Apps Script I get this error

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to slides.presentations.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].createTable: The page (SLIDES_API1632982083_36) could not be found.

```
function pleaseApiMySlides() {

  const pageId = Utilities.getUuid();
 
  const requests =  {

"title": "alice also made this"

  };


Slides.Presentations.create({

"title": "alice made this"

  });

 var preso =  Slides.Presentations.create(requests)

makeSlides(preso.presentationId);


}

function makeSlides(slidesId){
const preso = Slides.Presentations.get(slidesId);
console.log(preso.title);

const oid = Utilities.getUuid();

const requests = [{
    'createSlide': {
      'objectId': oid,
      
      'slideLayoutReference': {
        'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'
      }
    }
  }];

Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests},slidesId);

makeTables(slidesId,oid);

}


function makeTables(slidesId,slideObj){

console.log(slideObj)

const oid = Utilities.getUuid();

const requests = [{
  'createTable':{
"objectId": oid,
"rows": 3,
"columns": 2,
"elementProperties": {
  "pageObjectId": slideObj,
  }
  }

}];

Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests},slidesId);

}
```

I made a new function where instead of just passing the objectId for the slide from Apps Script to the Slides API I called the slides from the API and located the slide based on location from the list of slides. It returned the exact same objectId (facepalm) but for some reason it just liked it better that way. Geez. But it worked. It inserted the table on the existing slide that I had created from Apps Script.

```
function whatSlides(){

const slidesId = '1W-u8h2mQQB4XwJit9bp5XMU5GUuICDyTGSZQPSmlXT0/';
const sloj = 'SLIDES_API2007014672_36'

const preso = Slides.Presentations.get(slidesId);

var theSlides = preso.slides;
var objId = theSlides[8].objectId;
makeTables(preso.presentationId,objId)

}
```